# Cannot convert std::pair with toolset v120 (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm having a problem with toolset v120 and cannot compile my code, but it works fine with v140. My IntelliSense says:

> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=SHOPPURCHASE, _Pr=std::less<std::string>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, SHOPPURCHASE>>]" matches the argument list
>
> argument types are: (std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char, StrTraitMFC_DLL<char, ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>>, SHOPPURCHASE>)

```
BOOL SCHARDATA2::SETSHOPPURCHASE ( VECSHOP &vecSHOP )
{
    m_mapCharged.clear();
    DWORD dwSIZE = static_cast<DWORD>(vecSHOP.size());
    for ( DWORD i=0; i<dwSIZE; ++i )
    {
        const SHOPPURCHASE &sPURCHASE = vecSHOP[i];
        m_mapCharged.insert ( std::make_pair(sPURCHASE.strPurKey,sPURCHASE) );
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are trying to insert a `std::pair` that contains a `CString` where a `std::string` is expected.

`CString` is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`, so you need an explicit conversion between them. Try this:

```cpp
m_mapCharged.insert ( std::make_pair(std::string(sPURCHASE.strPurKey.c_str()), sPURCHASE) );
```

Alternatively: you can use `operator[]` instead of `insert()`:

```cpp
m_mapCharged[sPURCHASE.strPurKey.c_str()] = sPURCHASE;
```